# Why do my numbers I draw on fabricjs canvas don't get placed correctly?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to create a ruler in fabricjs, for that I draw lines and numbers in a for loop.
The lines and numbers are drawn correctly, but the 0 is always at the same place no matter what I add to s in `left: s+x,`. What am I doing wrong?

```
    let w = parseInt(width);
    let h = parseInt(height);
    let c = 0; //count
    let l = h-4; //line
    let z = 2; //"zoom"

    for(let s = 0; s < (w+1); s += z) {

        if (c % 10 === 0 || c === 0) {
            l = l - 20;     // draw every 10th line longer and add a number
            topRuler.add(new fabric.Text(`${c/10}`, {
                left: s+5,
                top: 0,
                fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                fontSize: 8,
                fill: "#090",
            }));
        } else if(c % 5 === 0) {
            l = l - 4; //every 5th line raised
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a working demo with JSFiddle or in a different way? It will be much easier and will draw more attention to your question.

Comment: Not that simple it's from a bigger project